# Meteor Angular2 and external changed of Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

I play around with a simple Meteor Angular 2 app which only read from database. I have another app which change the database. But when the database is changed, I got error on Meteor app.

```
Exception in queued task: EXCEPTION: Error in client/match.html:0:19
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'league' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'league' of undefined
at DebugAppView._View_MatchComponent0.detectChangesInternal (MatchComponent.template.js:101:59)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3001/packages/modules.js?hash=5bea6cc36ccb7076b2a2834b250a3c141ff0cd78:57326:14)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3001/packages/modules.js?hash=5bea6cc36ccb7076b2a2834b250a3c141ff0cd78:57415:44)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3001/packages/modules.js?hash=5bea6cc36ccb7076b2a2834b250a3c141ff0cd78:57346:34)
at DebugAppView._View_MatchesComponent1.detectChangesInternal (MatchesComponent.template.js:106:8)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3001/packages/modules.js?hash=5bea6cc36ccb7076b2a2834b250a3c141ff0cd78:57326:14)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3001/packages/modules.js?hash=5bea6cc36ccb7076b2a2834b250a3c141ff0cd78:57415:44)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3001/packages/modules.js?hash=5bea6cc36ccb7076b2a2834b250a3c141ff0cd78:57341:37)
at DebugAppView._View_MatchesComponent0.detectChangesInternal (MatchesComponent.template.js:65:8)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3001/packages/modules.js?hash=5bea6cc36ccb7076b2a2834b250a3c141ff0cd78:57326:14)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

I'm using autopublish which collection:

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
export let MatchCollection = new Mongo.Collection('matches');
```

And angular component:

```
export class MatchesComponent
{
    matches;
    constructor() {
        this.matches = MatchCollection.find();
    }
}
```

Note: Meteor Blaze version works well. And I'm new to Meteor Angular2.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using `*ngFor`.

You can use this more stable way

```
this.matches = MatchCollection.find().fetch();
```

`MatchCollection.find();` returns `Mongo.Cursor<any>`;

`MatchCollection.find().fetch();` returns `Array<any>`

Weird, the [bug](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/170) should be already fixed...

Comment: Thank you for information. I think `.fetch()` is not a good practice, but glad to see this bug fixed.

Comment: @LêTrầnTiếnTrung feel free to create another issue on github with a small reproduction, it will benefit the whole community. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the external change removed a property names `league` within the document, which your angular2 view uses somewhere.

Have a look at the document via `meteor mongo` to see how the document looks like in the storage before and after it has been modified by the external process.